# copy a file using an environment var in a docker file then execute the entrypoint

Tags: dockerfile

I'm trying to deploy a container and dynamically set the correct configuration (dev, qa, prod) at run time

basically I want to do this....(which doesn't work)

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY dist/ .
CMD cp configuration.$env.json configuration.json
ENTRYPOINT [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

And then when I start the container I pass the env that I want

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name MyUI -e env=qa myimage
```

Ideally I want the CMD to be a shell command, so I get the environment var and the ENTRYPOINT to be exec form (if this is possible)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `ARG` ? Also, if these are just qa, prod etc then okay but if you are planning to use secrets that way then better using `env_file` and encrypt it as `ARG` leaves traces

Comment: no, I need the variable to be set at run time i.e. when the container is first started - not as part of the image build stage.

Comment: When you need to provide it as runtime I think it's best you put the cp command in a script (entrypoint.sh) where you perform the cp and after that the nginx start command. In that script you can probably use an environment variable which you can set during the docker run command.

Comment: @lvthillo I'll give that a go

Comment: Maybe this can help a bit: https://github.com/lvthillo/docker-ghost-mysql/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml I'm starting a ghost container with env vars (to connect to a db). The env var's are picked up in the wait-for-it script (in the entrypoint, so during container startup), after completing the wait-for-it it (when it sure it can connect to the db, so it uses the env vars), it will start the real ghost app.